# Getting paired permutations in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, random

Context: I have a list of sports teams called `teamNames`, and I would like to generate their match-ups for each week. I'm not sure if permutations are even the right approach, but I feel like they would be. What I would ideally like is to pass a vector of team names to a function, and then have it give me a matrix where each row has that vector of team names in a different order, such that if I go through them in pairs, I'll get a unique set of match-ups for each row.

For example if my input is `teamNames <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")`, I want the output to be a matrix that says:

```
a  b  c  d
a  c  b  d
a  d  c  b
```

Edit: Further clarification: in this case, the matrix has given me three "weeks" of matchups. First week: "a" vs. "b"   and   "c" vs. "d"
Second week: "a" vs. "c"  and  "b" vs. "d" 
Third week: "a" vs. "d"  and  "b" vs. "c"

The closest I've gotten from reading other questions is to use the `permutations` function in the `gtools` package as follows:
`permutations(length(teamNames), 2, teamNames)`
This generates all the possible match-ups, but what it doesn't do is to divide them into sets/weeks. `combinations(length(teamNames), 4, teamNames` only gives me one set of matchups.

Comment: If you want all pairings to be unique, this can be tricky. Sounds like the [social golfer problem](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if 2 teams are chosen from the 4 teams, the rest two have to be matched. Then it is selecting 2 out of 4. Permutation may not be applied as 'a vs b' == 'b vs a'. No extra package is necessary as the utils package has combn().

```
> combn(teamNames, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "c"  "d"  "d"
```

Above shows selecting 2 teams from 4 and there are some duplication - selecting a and b equals to selecting c and d. If one of those duplicating cases are cancelled out, it'd be alright to set up a schedule.

### Update

@ Buckminster - I keep updating the code. In this update, the rest two are updated although there are still duplication. Also, among 4, if 2 are determined, the rest two have to be able to be determined (it is a similar idea how to solve a system of equations in linear algebra). In other words, I'm not sure why -1 was given probably by you.

```
# Update
teamNames <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
first <- combn(teamNames, 2, simplify = FALSE)
second <- lapply(first, function(x) teamNames[!teamNames %in% x])
bind <- rbind(do.call(cbind, first), do.call(cbind, second))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "c"  "d"  "d" 
[3,] "c"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "a"  "a" 
[4,] "d"  "d"  "c"  "d"  "c"  "b"
```

Let me check if duplication can be removed easily.

Comment: The OP provided a toy example with only four teams. S/he is looking for a solution that will generalize beyond four teams.

Comment: @ Buckminster (1) I'm not sure why your first and second comments are inconsistent. To reply to your first comment, I just mentioned that updates are being made and nothing was mentioned about # teams. (2) For 4 teams, determining 2 teams would suffice to determine 4 teams. (3) The situation wouldn't be quite different for cases of even-numbered teams (eg, 4 teams have to be determined once 2 teams are determined among 6 teams). (4) Yes, the code that I've added is not complete and may not be helpful. However I don't think that -1 should be given as, at least, I spent some time for good.

Comment: @JaehyeonKim While it's not exactly what I was looking for, I appreciate your help. I've upvoted your answer to cancel out the negative one.